# "aspnet_regiis -pa" doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I use Protected Configuration to store sensitive data encrypted in the Web.config file of our asp.net application.
I have followed the steps in [Walkthrough: Creating and Exporting an RSA Key Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede.aspx) to generate and export a private key.
I have followed the steps in [Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx) to encrypt a section of the Web.config file using that key.

My problem is that I am unable to use that key on the test environment, due to strange behaviour from the `aspnet_regiis` command.

I *have* been able to get the thing to work on a colleague's computer that runs Windows 8. Both the `aspnet_regiis -pi` command (importing the private key) and the `aspnet_regiis -pa` (granting access to the private key) worked without problems there.

On the test environment that runs Windows 7, I have been able to successfully import the private key into the key container using `aspnet_regiis -pi <KeyContainer> <KeyFile>`.
But when I try `aspnet_regiis -pa <KeyContainer> <account-name>`, the command just lists it's command line options. It does not indicate failure or success.

All these environments use .Net Framework v4.

I have looked at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/107134/when-i-run-aspnet-regiis-exe-it-just-shows-me-the-command-line-options-and-does), but the difference is that I was able to execute `aspnet_regiis -pi <KeyContainer> <KeyFile>`. Nor did it make a difference to execute `aspnet_regiis -lk` as is suggested there.

The question is: how can I grant the application access to the contents of the Key Container, so that it can decrypt the Web.config? Why is aspnet_regiis acting as if the "-pa" option does not exist, rather than giving me a "Success" or "Failed" message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that we were using the wrong version of aspnet_regiis.

We called aspnet_regiis from the `%Windows%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319` directory.
When calling it from `%Windows%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319`, the 64-bit version, the command reported success.

Still, an error message would have been helpful...

EDIT:
It seems that the Key Container is not available unless you have a User Profile.
When, on another server, we allowed the account that used "Logon as a Service" to access the Key Container, it failed - even though it was in the Administrator group. When we logged on physically, creating a User Profile in doing so, the Key Container *did* become available.